# Adjust parent layout in a gallery to remote image's width after it has been loaded

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a gallery item which consists of a `RelativeLayout` containing an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. (see my masterpiece of drawing below)

[image: LayoutProblem skillfully visualized]

Upon start of the activity one gallery item takes up all the space of the screen making the image look lost on the left side and the textview (blue banner) way too long. I want to have several items next to each other depending on the image width.

The image is being replaced after loaded from a server so I can't know how wide the image will be exactly when I start/layout the activity.

I now want to adjust the `RelativeLayout`'s width to the width of the image after it has been loaded and placed into the view.

I already played around with the `getLayoutParams()` method inside the ListAdapter for the Gallery but this leads to ANRs and no result at all.

Here's the layout for my gallery item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/item_wrap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/item_margin"
        >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/item_title_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Some longer title so you can see how the text behaves"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/title_gradient_grey"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help how to relayout after the image has been inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should resize image after downloading from server.This is necessary coz the image you are downloading may be of much bigger size and set property for ImageView as

`<ImageView ...
           android:scaleType="fitXY"` this would lead you to scaling.

other option is

`<ImageView ...
           android:scaleType="center"` if you don't want scaling.

Comment: fitXY leads to the image being scaled out of ration to the full width and height of the gallery. This doesn't work.

Comment: if you don't want scaling then use `android:scaleType=center` only

Comment: This could acutually work, don't know why I didn't see that. If you change your answer using the center-scaleType instead I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @StefanHoth I edited it.Please accept it as correct answer if it helped you ? now I really need those reputation points.